# Parse file in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I want to parse file in MatLab, the data in the text with this format.

```
15.01245  20.478
12.589  58.256
```

**i used this function:**

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
tline = fgets(fid);
while ischar(tline)
disp(tline)
tline = fgets(fid);
end

fclose(fid);
```

It gave me the lines, but i want to extract it and store it as array
like:

**data(1,1)=15.01245  , data(1,2)= 20.478**

how i can do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call to

```
data = load('file.txt')
```

Comment: Wow this is much better , Thanks